# How to replace with expanded tab in vim

Tags: vim

I don't have a problem, I'm just curious.

Here is a part of my .vimrc.

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

I want to replace in text all `notab` with     `<-here is a tab`

so the command should be:

```
:%s/notab/^I<-here is a tab/
```

which gives me real tab, so in order to replace it by 4 space in need to call
`:retab`

Same results in a single call (directly add 4 spaces):

`:%s/notab/    <-here is a tab/`

But it is not convenient, this first version include real tab in the text, which need to be re-tabed and the second version depends on the number of spaces defined to be one tab.

Is there any general way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to do? Replace `notab` with a tabulation or replace it with 4 spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do exactly what you want:

```
:%s/notab/\=repeat(" ", &tabstop)/ge
```

Comment: This works only if “notab” happens to be in position where (col-1) % &tabstop == 0.

Comment: @ZyX Somehow I never quite committed my edit that said as much. Mmm. It was a very busy work week... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

@sehe’s answer works well if `notab` is placed at the start of the line (when (col-1) % &tabstop == 0, but with variable &tabstop this is guaranteed to happen only when col==1). If you are not fine neither with `%s/notab/\t/ge | retab` (i.e. your variant joined into one line using bar symbol) (perhaps, because there are already tabs that are not to be retabbed, I do not see any other reasons) nor with @sehe’s answer you have to use much more complex code:

```
function ToExpTab(pat)
    for lnr in range(1, line('$'))
        let line=''
        let chunks=split(getline(lnr), a:pat, 1)
        if len(chunks)<=1
            continue
        endif
        for chunk in chunks[:-2]
            let line.=chunk
            let line.=repeat(' ', &tabstop-(strdisplaywidth(line))%&tabstop)
        endfor
        let line.=chunks[-1]
        call setline(lnr, line)
    endfor
endfunction
call ToExpTab('notab')
```